# How to replace elements by value in a list of lists in Python?

Tags: python, list, replace, list-comprehension

I have:

```
 counts = [[2, 2, 2, 0], [2, 2, 1, 0]]
 countsminusone = [[1, 1, 1, -1], [1, 1, 0, -1]] #Which is counts - 1
```

For every value, where countsminusone is 0 or less than 0, I want to replace it with 1.

```
 countsminusone1 = [[1 if x == 0 or x < 0 else x for x in pair] for pair in countsminusone] #I cannot get this to work
```

And then divide counts by countsminusone

```
Divide = [[n/d for n, d in zip(subq, subr)] for subq, subr in zip(counts, countsminusone)] #This should work if the above works
```

Comment: `x == 0 or x < 0` == `x < 1` for integers...

Comment: Or at least x <= 0...

Comment: What makes you think that it doesn't work?  Please provide the real and expected results.

Comment: It works, except you forgot to replace `countsminusone` by `countsminusone1` in your last line...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are making this much too complicated. Let's state what you actually want to do in the simplest way:

> GOAL: Divide every number n in list of lists by n - 1 or, if n - 1 <= 0, by 1.

This can be done without creating extra lists and zipping:

```
counts = [[2, 2, 2, 0], [2, 2, 1, 0]]
divided = [[i / max(i - 1, 1) for i in sublst] for sublst in counts]
```

Note that in this case, `max(i - 1, 1)` will *always* be 1.

Comment: Right, best answer

Answer (score 1):

It works, except you forgot to replace `countsminusone` by `countsminusone1` in your last line.

```
countsminusone1 = [[1 if x <= 0 else x for x in pair] for pair in countsminusone]
Divide = [[n/d for n, d in zip(subq, subr)] for subq, subr in zip(counts, countsminusone1)]
```